# rsync with filter

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to copy source code files from a remote file system to the local server. The source code file extensions are *.?pp, *.[CHh].

How can I run an rsync to copy the remote file system hierarchy and the source code files, excluding everything else (binaries, libraries, objects, repository files...)?

PS: I used this horrible line so far, there must be an easier solution:

```
$ rsync --include "*/" --include="*/*" --include="*/*/*" --include="*/*/*/*" --include="*.[CHh]" --include="*.?pp" --exclude="*" -axW user@remote/my/remote/dir ./
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double-star to simplify the includes:

```
rsync -axW --exclude="*" --include="**/.[CHh]" --include "**/*.?pp" ...
```